# Redirect from observer in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2.2.5. I have created event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`. In that I need to check when user click on add to cart button then I want to check if particular product exist in cart then user can not add that product.

So for that if user add that product then he should redirect on same page with error message.

**Example:**
If user added product A in cart. Then if he add product A1 then I want to redirect to last page with error message "You can not add A1 in cart".

Currently I did this but I have to add `exit` or `die()` after redirect code.

How can I achieve this without `exit` or `die()`.

**CODE :**

```
if ($condition) {
     $this->messageManager->addError(__("Error Message", $var));
     $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
     die();
}
if ($condition) {
     $this->messageManager->addError(__("Another Error message"));
     $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
     die();
}
```

Here I have to add die().

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception like this:

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Sorry, but seems to be a problem with this product, please try again later.')
```

And then you don't need to add exit() or die()

Cheers